# Send bytes via tcp/ip with android phone faster

Tags: java, android, tcp, ip, android-camera

I am taking pictures with the camera2 api for Android on a Nexus 6. It's taking virtually no time at all from when my code reaches the end of onImageAvailable() to when it's called again.

However, it's taking ~700ms to send my picture over tcp/ip.

```
private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = 
new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) 
    {
        Image image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
        if(image.getPlanes().length == 0)
            return;

        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        if(buffer == null)
            return;

        byte[] pictureBytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(pictureBytes);

        mOutputStream.write((String.valueOf(pictureBytes.length) + "....").getBytes());
        // FROM HERE
        mOutputStream.write(pictureBytes);
        // TO HERE TAKES ~700ms
        mOutputStream.flush();
}
```

My connection is created in another thread, as android requires, with the following code:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(#);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
```

Note: mOutputStream in the main thread is equal to outputStream. I pass outputStream to the main thread.

I've tried using BufferedOutputStream and that was actually slower.

The link speed between my phone and the device that it's connected to is 130Mbps. With images that are less than 2MB, I should be able to send at least 8 pictures a second.

How do I reduce the 700ms time? Thank you!

Comment: compressing the image will help

Comment: "With images that are less than 2MB" -- that's a fairly low-resolution photo. Are you sure about that? Also, when you examined the server that you wrote, what are you doing with the bytes that are read in? Your 700ms is probably blocking on the server reading in the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do have 130mbps connection to your other device if you're using TCP you won't be able to use all that bandwidth immediately. This because of TCP congestion control mechanism called *slow-start*.

At the beginning of each connection TCP starts with sending small amount of data because the capacity of the link is unknown. This amount of traffic sent before the ACK is received is defined by *congestion window* and depending on the configured MSS (Maximum Segment Size) it could be 2-4 times the MSS. Exact amount is defined in RFC5681:

```
   If SMSS > 2190 bytes:
       IW = 2 * SMSS bytes and MUST NOT be more than 2 segments
   If (SMSS > 1095 bytes) and (SMSS <= 2190 bytes):
       IW = 3 * SMSS bytes and MUST NOT be more than 3 segments
   If SMSS <= 1095 bytes:
       IW = 4 * SMSS bytes and MUST NOT be more than 4 segments
```

After receiving each ACK the size of congestion window is increased by the size of MSS. This actually means that the window size grows exponentially. Even though the exponential growth enables TCP to reach the maximum bandwidth very fast, for relatively small files this fast is not fast enough. Even if your connection is 100mbps you won't be able to send 8 pictures per second because the transfer time is relatively short and the window size will be too small for a considerable period of that transfer time to allow you to use the full bandwidth available.

Depending on the round trip time (to the server and back) it may even take 500ms to send the first 1MB of data so there is a small chance that you will be able to send more than 2 or maybe 3 images per second.

Answer (score -1):

I switched from Java to C# to read in the bytes. That was the main bottleneck. I'm up to 3.33 fps; this includes the time writing to disk.

But yes, I verified the pictures were less than 2MB.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: If reading was the bottleneck, it was your reading code, not the platform.